# What's With the Server Connection Error That Shows a Bunch of HTML?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

So, as of yesterday, I've been unable to connect to any of four different servers, which work fine for others.  Of the 4, three give me the following error:

[image: HTML?]

---

What's up with this?  Why is it showing HTML?

Comment: The "failed to log in" at the left might mean something :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical reason it's showing html? The client probably expects an error message in plaintext that explains why the login failed. The client is receiving an actual html document and doesn't do any checking before it loads all that text into the spot where the error message should be.

This could be any number of issues where your client is getting back html from something between you and the minecraft server (such as a network security layer or wifi login page, like Amazed suggested) or the minecraft server itself producing 404, 500 or any number of other error pages for any number of reasons.

Considering that it's happening on 3 of 4 servers, maybe they haven't upgraded to 1.5 yet?

Comment: No, the "server is too old" error is a Java exception message.

Comment: If you 'view source' and look for the DOCTYPE tag in the middle of the HTML code, that'll point you to the part of the document where this HTML has been inserted and then if you can understand HTML you might be able to identify more info about what it is trying to display

Comment: @Lazygun a) the DOCTYPE tag is always at the top of an HTML document b) this is the minecraft client, so there is no 'view source'

Answer (score 7):

There are reports that Trend Micro security products (and some other web-filtering soft/hardware) sometimes block Minecraft connections and try to display a "Warning" HTML page. Check your security software and make sure it allows Minecraft to connect.